# How to spawn random objects in endless runner 3d?

Tags: c#, 3d, unity-game-engine

Hi all I am developing an endless runner game and need help on solving an issue. My version of the endless runner is where the player moves along the z-axis while tiles spawning in-front of the player. The tiles have 3 lanes. So my issue is this. I have this spawning script which I got from researching the net and ran into the issue the script is written where the tiles moving under the player rather than player running forward. I tried to convert it so that that objects are spawned in front of the player (z-axis) but I didn't quite achieve what I intended for.

So my errors are,

- objects (obstacles) are spawning behind the player and eventually stops
- objects are spawned only in one lane.

So how do I how do I rectify above errors?

Here's my script.

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

    [Space(10)]
    [Header("Obstacles:")]
    public float objectSpawnWait;
    public Vector3 randPos1;
    public Vector3 randPos2;
    public Vector3 randPos3;
    public float spawnZ; //distance between player and the object 
    public float spawnDistance; //distance between object
    public GameObject[] obstacles;

    private Transform playerTranform;

    void Start()
    {
        playerTranform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(playerTranform.position.z > spawnZ * spawnDistance)
        {
            StartCoroutine(SpawnObstacle());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnObstacle()
    {
        if (obstacles.Length > 0)
        {
            int randomObstacle = Random.Range(0, obstacles.Length);            

            GameObject obstacle = Instantiate(obstacles[randomObstacle]);
            obstacle.transform.SetParent(transform);
            MoveObjectsToTheFront(obstacle);
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    }

    private void MoveObjectsToTheFront(GameObject moveObject)
    {
        int randomPosNum = Random.Range(0, 2);
        Vector3 randomPosition;

        if (randomPosNum == 0)
            randomPosition = randPos1; // Vector3(2, 0.5, 5)
        else if (randomPosNum == 1)
            randomPosition = randPos2; // Vector3(0, 0.5, 5)
        else
            randomPosition = randPos3; // Vector3(-2, 0.5, 5)

        moveObject.transform.position = randomPosition * spawnZ;
        spawnZ += spawnDistance;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [Endless Runner Pack](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/87901) from Unity.

Comment: SetParent() takes an actual transform object as an argument. Also, you need to create a Vector3 object and set the Vector3.x property. Your implementation is going to eventually start to cause errors because values for position are going to get to big. This is why you should move the ground tiles and not the player.

Comment: @C.Parcell my aim is once I run a bit far to reset everything back to the zero position. But Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Isn't `Random.Range(int, int)` exclusive on the upper bound? That would mean `randomPosNum` could only be `0` or `1`, but yet you have three options.

Comment: @AdamKingsley you are right. I should put 0,3. Thank you.